# write_rich_string with dynamic values (Perl)

Tags: bash, shell, perl, unix, perl-module

I am pretty much new to perl and i am put into a new perl project . Me being a C developer had a few hiccups initially, but somehow managed to fix the code expect for the below logic.

I am using write_rich_string in order to do different formatting within the same cell. Here is the snippet of the code where i am getting the error.

```
$worksheet->write_rich_string(0,0,$format1,$text1,$format2,$text2,$wrap);
```

**the code is working great until one of the text1 or text2 comes as null. Is there any way i can handle the null inside the write_rich_string()?**

Please note i have 7 texts with its corresponding formats to be inserted. I have  just shown 2 texts.

Request your assistance guys. Please help.

**Update 2** : I also tried the below approach such that i can concatenate the Worksheet format(Red colour font cell) with the string in a variable and put it inside the write_rich_string() function . But that gives the below message and the excel row has the below message instead.

```
if ($mdr_count == 1) { $var.="$lav_cell,$mrd"; }
if ($lwd_count == 1) { $var.="$red_cell,$lwd"; }
print "The value is ${var}";

$worksheet->write_rich_string($row,$pos,$var);
```

## Output :

```
**Excel::Writer::XLSX::Format=HASH(0x1427aac)**,Provide Missing Required **DataExcel::Writer::XLSX::Format=HASH(0x1426e7c)**,Loan is late by more than 30 days
```

It just converted the format into a string and pasted that in the excel row.

Comment: In perl null values referenced as `undef`. To check for null: `if (defined($text1)) { ... }`

Comment: @wolfrevokcat i have edited the question, i have tried the same approach and i am not able to do it.

Comment: Can't you just change `null` values to empty strings? `$text1 = $text1 eq '' || $text1 eq 'null' ? '' : $text1`

Comment: If u place null value ie ..'' that is not going to work on the write_rich_string(). The format cannot be applied to a null vaiue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of my mind you can have an array with the string (text) that you want to enter in the spreadsheet. Search the array for `undef` elements and change them to `NULL` strings.

Sample of working code based on the code that you provide us.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# Create a new Excel workbook
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );

# Add a worksheet
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

#  Add and define a format
my $format1 = $workbook->add_format();
$format1->set_bold();
$format1->set_color( 'red' );
$format1->set_align( 'center' );

#  Add and define a format
my $format2 = $workbook->add_format();
$format2->set_bold();
$format2->set_color( 'blue' );
$format2->set_align( 'center' );

#  Add and define a format
my $format3 = $workbook->add_format();
$format3->set_bold();
$format3->set_color( 'orange' );
$format3->set_align( 'center' );

# Search array and replace undef element(s)
my @text = ('string1', undef, 'string3');
defined or $_ = "NULL" for @text;
# Or simply empty string
# defined or $_ = "" for @text;
# Or simply white space
# defined or $_ = " " for @text;

# Write some strings with multiple formats.
my ($row, $col) = 0;
$worksheet->write_rich_string( $row, $col,
                   $format1, $text[0],
                   $format2, $text[1],
                   $format3, $text[2] );
```

Does this work for you?

Looking forward to your reply, BR.

Comment: since u are undef value with "NULL" the String "NULL" will get printed on the excel. I dont want that null to be printed on the excel. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @VimalBhaskar, I have added one more line under this command:

`# Or simply empty string # defined or $_ = "" for @text;`

This does exactly the same but instead of `NULL` it prints an empty string with no white space. You can replace it with `defined or $_ = " " for @text;`.

It was just a sample of code, I do not know what you want to do in case you do have a `NULL` value you have not provide us this part of information.

Provide us an output in case you do have a `NULL` e.g. output: `Text1 Text2` etc...

Looking forward to your update.

Comment: Negative voting, what for? Did someone tried it and did not work the sample of code for them? Is there any logic of voting on this site or randomly people vote negatively?

Comment: I didnt negative vote @Thanos. And looks like $_ = "" for text will not be placing the format. Anyways i am upvoting for the effort u took. Thank you. I anyways solved the issue.

Comment: Hello @VimalBhaskar, I did not thought that you down vote but I am wondering why someone would? The proposed solution works and resolves the problem, maybe not the way that you want but it tackles the issue. Can you also provide us the solution for future reference that someone might have the same problem as you had?

Comment: I up voted for u thanos :), since u got a downvote(I never downvoted u :) ).  and by the way i used ' 'to  process. Please note this is not null, but a blank space inbetween the qoutes.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar, thanks but if you see my answer also included `# Or simply white space # defined or $_ = " " for @text;` which will match your problem.

Comment: Didn't see that. Thank you. :)

Comment: Make sure u go ' ' instead of " ". Thats the only difference.